# php for each table in database

Tags: php, sql, foreach

Trying to create a drop down list for each table I have in a database.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('show tables');
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
foreach ($result as $table) {
    echo $table;
}
```

However, the echo is returning 'Array' for each table instead of the table name.

How do I make it return the table name?

Comment: Instead of echo use var_dump and check what is displayed.

Comment: If you `print_r($result);` you will see it probably has an array with `Tables_in_{yourdatabasenamehere}`

Comment: Yeah it showed thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there is only one element in the array, this should work:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('show tables');
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
foreach ($result as $table) {
  echo current($table);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try $table[0]

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('show tables');
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();

foreach ($result as $table) {
    echo $table[0] . '<br>';
}
```

var_dump($result)

```
array(59) {
  [0] array(2) {
    ["Tables_in_information_schema"] "CHARACTER_SETS"
    [0] "CHARACTER_SETS"
  }
  [1] array(2) {
    ["Tables_in_information_schema"] "COLLATIONS"
    [0] "COLLATIONS"
  }
  ...
```